# For Loop not advancing

Tags: matlab, resize, jpeg

I'm trying to read in a large number of `jpg` files using a `for` loop. But for some reason, the `k` index is not advancing. I just get `A` as a 460x520x3 uint8. Am I missing something?

My goal with this code is to convert all the `jpg` images to the same size. Since I haven't been able to advance through the images, I can't quite tell if I'm doing it right.

```
nFrames = length(date); % Number of frames.
for k = 1:nFrames-1 % Number of days
    % Set file under consideration
    A = imread(['map_EUS_' datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)),'yyyy_mm_dd') '_O3_MDA8.jpg']);

    % Size of existing image A.
    [rowsA, colsA, numberOfColorChannelsA] = size(A);

    % Read in and get size of existing image B (the next image).
    B = imread(['map_EUS_' datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k+1)),'yyyy_mm_dd') '_O3_MDA8.jpg']);
    [rowsB, colsB, numberOfColorChannelsB] = size(B);

    % Size of B does not match A, so resize B to match A's size.
    B = imresize(B, [rowsA colsA]);

    eval(['print -djpeg map_EUS_' datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)),'yyyy_mm_dd') '_O3_MDA8_test.jpg']);
    end
end
```

Comment: What is `nFrames` supposed to be? Does `date` correspond to the date returned by MATLAB or some local variables?

Comment: `date` is `365x1` cell with dates for a year in `datenum` form. `nFrames` is supposed to length of `date`, so it's a double that is equal to `365`.

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding nFrames = 365? Just to make sure that length(date) is deriving what you're expecting? .

Comment: I just tried it. Same thing - I just get one image for the first day only. In the final version, I can't use `nFrames = 365` because some years have `366` days.

Comment: I tried moving the `eval(...)` to outside the first `end` and that did help - it created a list of `jpg` files, but they are all of the first day. Do you think I need to write an `else` statement. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: You need to check what `datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)),'yyyy_mm_dd')` is returning.  Also, why all that `print`/`eval` stuff rather than just `imwrite`?

Comment: @nkjt `datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)),'yyyy_mm_dd')` is returning the each date (i.e. 2006_01_01) and advancing forward. So the filename of the jpg that is created is advancing, but the image itself is not. I added a line in my question above because now I'm thinking maybe it's not working because I only created an `if` statement for if the images are not the same size with nothing about what should happen if the images are the same size.

Comment: @nkjt Using `imwrite` solved the problem. Do you want to write an answer saying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use `imread` to read the image in, it makes sense to use `imwrite` to write it out, rather than `print/eval` (also you should always think twice about using `eval` in MATLAB, and then think again).

You could also speed up this code somewhat - you just want to resize all the images to the size of whichever the first one is, so you don't need to keep reading in images to measure the size of them.  Use `imfinfo` to get the size, then read in, resize, and write out `B` only.